# Rendering HTML/ Cannot Get / node.js error

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

Ok guys, when I run my code with node.js and try to open the port on Chrome I get the error "Cannot Get /" instead of rendering the form . There are several questions on this, here but unfortunatly none helps. It would be great if you could take a look at the code and maybe state the problem. 
Also here what I am trying to do : I am using import.io to take some data from trip advisor, which comes to me as JSON objects. Then I want to use a form to filter the names of the places, and give the user what he wants.

I know import.io is in beta and not a popular tool yet but it I believe problem is not caused by it as if I just print out the data using console.log it prints out well. So the problem you be with taking the request or rendering the html i think

Here is the html :

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
        <body>
            <form action="example2.js" method="get">
                <input type="radio" name="catagory" value="Church"> Church </br>
                <input type="radio" name="catagory" value="Piazza"> Piazza </br>
                <input type="radio" name="catagory" value="Basilica"> Basilica </br>    
                <input type="submit" name="Submit"> Submit
            </form>
        </body>
</html>
```

And here is the JS document for Node.js

```
var http=require('http');
var importio = require("import-io").client;
var io = new importio("19781bd4-6f35-405f-88ef-2f3819b42d9c",     "T7Twn5JRXweKI9/9bQ5MSdXMpwUTdYsNgFcJQKTj0b8qKea960gm1R/Tf/EMMYhMUzyLVbNFlf1gZ/rLK2bpZA==",     "import.io");
 var express = require('express');
var app= express();
 var bodyParser= require('body-parser');
 var data = [];
 var runningQueries = 0;
    // Make sure that you have connection with import.io 
io.connect(function(connected) {
  if (!connected) {
    console.error("Unable to connect");
    return;
  }
// Callback for handling the message from import.io
var callback = function(finished, message) {

if (message.type == "DISCONNECT") {
  console.error("The query was cancelled as the client was disconnected");
}

if (message.type == "MESSAGE") {
  if (message.data.hasOwnProperty("errorType")) {
    console.error("Got an error!", message.data);
  } else {
    console.log("Got data!", message.data);
    data = data.concat(message.data.results);
  }
}

   if (finished) {
  console.log("Done single query");
  runningQueries--;
  if (runningQueries <= 0) {
    runningQueries = 0;
    console.log(data);
    console.log("All queries completed");
    for(i=0; i<data.length ; i++){
      console.log(data[i].name)
    }
  }
}
  }

//HANDLING REQUEST 
app.use(bodyParser());

  app.get('/example2.js',function(request, response){

  var typeplace = request.body.catagory;
   for(i=0; i<data.length ; i++){
      if((data[i].name).indexOf(typeplace) === -1){
        data.splice(i, 1);
      }
   }
  })
 runningQueries += 2;

  io.query({
"connectorGuids": [
  "e7aecf09-8e0b-449c-9058-60ee01debd3d"
],
"input": {
  "webpage/url": "http://www.tripadvisor.com.tr/Attractions-g187791-Activities-Rome_Lazio.html"
}
  }, callback);

  io.query({
"connectorGuids": [
  "e7aecf09-8e0b-449c-9058-60ee01debd3d"
],
"input": {
  "webpage/url": "http://www.tripadvisor.com.tr/Attractions-g187791-Activities-Rome_Lazio.html"
}
  }, callback);
});

app.listen(8000);
```

Sorry if my code if unreadable because of hanging parents etc. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you don't have a (GET) route defined for `/`, at least in the code you've provided.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is no place in your node js code where you render the "/" page.  Since it looks like you are using express already, try the following:

```
app.get('/', function(req, response) {
  response.render('YOUR HTML FORM FILE NAME');
});
```

Comment: Did you get an answer you were looking for?